# Exception handling in streams with Either

Tags: java, functional-programming, vavr

#### Background

I have been fascinated with [Scott WLaschin's Railway Oriented Programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srQt1NAHYC0) model of handling exceptions: have a side channel, where all the bad stuff will be processed, and keep the good stuff on the main track. Picture below:

[image]

#### Problem

A common pattern that comes up in daily code is like :

- Have a list of data
- Validate each one of them
- The validation can throw exceptions

#### Question

How to do this in a way that resembles the railway-oriented model discussed above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Somjit's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67556075/542270) answer shows correct approach however it uses an outer variable (`errors`) to accumulate the errors. This is, in general, discouraged since we should avoid the global/external state.

You can use vavr's [`partition`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/latest/io/vavr/collection/Traversable.html#partition(java.util.function.Predicate)) method to split the stream into two: one with errors and one with validated ints. They are both put into a tuple:

```
public void composeExceptions() {
   final Tuple2<Stream<Either<IllegalArgumentException, Integer>>, Stream<Either<IllegalArgumentException, Integer>>> both = Stream.range(1, 11)
            .map(this::validate)
            .partition(Either::isLeft);

   both._1.map(Either::getLeft).forEach(e -> System.out.println("Got error: " + e.getMessage()));
   both._2.map(Either::get).forEach(i -> System.out.println("Validated correctly: " + i));
}
```

**EDIT**
Actually there also other options like:

```
Stream
   .range(1, 11)
   .map(this::validate)
   .toJavaStream()
   .collect(Collectors.teeing(
      Collectors.filtering(Either::isLeft, toList()),
      Collectors.filtering(Either::isRight, toList()),
      (errors, ints) -> new Tuple2<>(errors.stream().map(Either::getLeft), ints.stream().map(Either::get))));
```

which uses `teeing` which is quite interesting collector from java API. Unfortunately it mixes vavr and java API which is not great, not terrible.

And:

```
Stream
   .range(1, 11)
   .map(this::validate)
   .collect(
      () -> new Tuple2<>(List.<RuntimeException>empty().asJavaMutable(), List.<Integer>empty().asJavaMutable()),
      (tuple, either) -> {
         either.peekLeft(tuple._1::add);
         either.peek(tuple._2::add);
      },
      (t1, t2) -> {
         t1._1.addAll(t2._1);
         t1._2.addAll(t2._2);
      }
    )
       .map((exceptions, integers) -> new Tuple2<>(List.ofAll(exceptions), List.ofAll(integers)));
```

which uses vavr API only but underneath uses java `List` since a mutable structure is required here.

Comment: Nice! Seems like currently in alpha release only. Hopefully we see it in general version soon

Comment: @Somjit the link is to alpha version, but it's included in the base branch as well. It's one of the basic functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of handling the exceptions on the "side track" is by using the `peekleft` method Vavr provides, which consumes the `Either.Left()` side. We can plug our exception processing logic in there, and leave our `Either.right()` stuff nicely on the main track without any ugliness.

I am pretty sure this can be improved, and would love ideas on improving this.

```java
List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();

@Test
public void composeExceptions() {

    List<Integer> valids = IntStream.range(0, 11).boxed()
            .map(this::validate)             // throws exceptions
            .peek(this::handleExceptions)    // process left/exceptions on the side
            .flatMap(Value::toJavaStream)    // flatmap is right based
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("========= Good ones =========");
    System.out.println(valids);
    System.out.println("========= Bad Ones =========");
    errors.forEach(System.out::println);

}

public void handleExceptions(Either<IllegalArgumentException, Integer> either) {
    either.peekLeft(e -> errors.add(e.getMessage())); // is this a monadic bind ???
}

public Either<IllegalArgumentException, Integer> validate(Integer i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) return Either.right(i);
    return Either.left(new IllegalArgumentException("odd one's out : " + i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also was fascinated by the presentation pointed out. I will add here some part of the code that I am using for handling checked exception (for these purposes I recommend taking a look at this presentation :
[Exception Handling in Functional and Reactive Programming by Venkat Subramaniam](https://youtu.be/S5tLVsvbHBg) )

First of all this is how I call it :

```
import static Monader.fnMaybeToMaybe;
import static Monader.fnOnValue;
import static Monader.fnValueToMaybe;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class RailTrackRunner {

    @Test
    public void goingThruSomeClassNames() {

        List<String> classNames = List.of(
                "lombok.Getter",
                "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue",
                "dummy.vrs.invalid",
                "lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j");

        System.out.println("\nV1");

        classNames.stream()
                .map(Maybe::ofValue)
                .map(fnMaybeToMaybe(Class::forName)) // throws ClassNotFoundException
                .map(fnOnValue(Class::getSimpleName))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\nV2");

        classNames.stream()
                .map(fnValueToMaybe(Class::forName)) // throws ClassNotFoundException
                .map(fnOnValue(Class::getSimpleName))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```

and the necessary pieces are these:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ExceptionThrower<T, R, EX extends Exception> {

    R apply(T t) throws EX;

}

----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- 

import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class Maybe<VAL, EXC extends Exception> {

    public static <STVAL, STEXC extends Exception> Maybe<STVAL, STEXC> ofValue(@NonNull STVAL out) {
        return new Maybe<STVAL, STEXC>(out, null);
    }

    public static <STVAL, STEXC extends Exception> Maybe<STVAL, STEXC> ofExc(@NonNull STEXC exc) {
        return new Maybe<STVAL, STEXC>(null, exc);
    }

    private VAL value;
    private EXC exc;

    private Maybe(VAL value, EXC exc) {
        this.value = value;
        this.exc = exc;
        if (!(hasValue() ^ hasException()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid state for Maybe");
    }

    public boolean hasValue() {
        return value != null;
    }

    public boolean hasException() {
        return exc != null;
    }

}

----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- 

import java.util.function.Function;

public class Monader<IN, OUT, EX extends Exception> {

    public static <IN, OUT, EX extends Exception> Function<Maybe<IN, EX>, Maybe<OUT, EX>> fnOnValue(Function<IN, OUT> simpleValueFunction) {
        return maybeIn -> {
            if (maybeIn.hasValue()) {
                OUT outValue = simpleValueFunction.apply(maybeIn.getValue());
                return Maybe.ofValue(outValue);
            } else // maybeIn.hasException()
                return Maybe.ofExc(maybeIn.getExc());
        };
    }

    public static <IN, OUT, EX extends Exception> Function<Maybe<IN, EX>, Maybe<OUT, EX>> fnMaybeToMaybe(ExceptionThrower<IN, OUT, EX> exceptionThrower) {
        return maybeIn -> {
            if (maybeIn.hasValue())
                return executeThrower(exceptionThrower, maybeIn.getValue());
            else // maybeIn.hasException()
                return Maybe.ofExc(maybeIn.getExc());
        };
    }

    public static <IN, OUT, EX extends Exception> Function<IN, Maybe<OUT, EX>> fnValueToMaybe(ExceptionThrower<IN, OUT, EX> exceptionThrower) {
        return in -> executeThrower(exceptionThrower, in);
    }

    private static <IN, OUT, EX extends Exception> Maybe<OUT, EX> executeThrower(ExceptionThrower<IN, OUT, EX> exceptionThrower, IN in) {
        try {
            OUT out = exceptionThrower.apply(in);
            return Maybe.ofValue(out);
        } catch (RuntimeException rexc) {
            throw rexc;
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                EX castedEsc = (EX) exc;
                return Maybe.ofExc(castedEsc);
            } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exc);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).